# zimbra Error when installing

Tags: zimbra

Can you guys help?
I have set up an ubuntu server 12.04 for Zimbra, I download zcs 8.0.2 and put it in /opt/zimbra. but when I run install.sh, even though prerequisites ARE Found and I Agree to the License and select packages to intall, the folder is removed and I get the following error:

./install.sh line 339: /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsetup.pl: No such file or directory

And when I go back to looking for that .pl I don't find anything, everyhting's wiped out !

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ZCS 8.0.2 on 12.04.

Please download 8.0.7 from [here](http://www.zimbra.com/downloads/os-downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the installation folder in `/opt/zimbra`, cause the Zimbra installation script will erase everything in /opt/zimbra folder. That's why you get the `"No such file"` error.

Instead of `/opt/zimbra`, you could use `/opt` or even your user home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the installer script file

```
# ./install.sh
```

Or on platforms other than RHEL:

```
# ./install.sh --platform-override
```

For more details http://www.tslonlinestuff.com/2018/04/zimbra-zcs-installation-on-centos-7.html